# Outbound Messaging Response failure

Tags: workflow, workflowoutboundmessage

I am getting "org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; Premature end of file" issue while making a outbound Messaging request, though my endpoint system/application is receiving the expected request from the SF Outbound Messaging.

Not sure where its going wrong as O am even sending the proper Notification Response back to SF.

Please see the request and response sample below.

**Notification Request recieved :**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <soapenv:Body>
        <notifications xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2005/09/outbound">
            <OrganizationId>***********</OrganizationId>
            <ActionId>04k28000000k9bNAAQ</ActionId>
            <SessionId>
                00D...
            </SessionId>
            <EnterpriseUrl>***************</EnterpriseUrl>
            <PartnerUrl>**********</PartnerUrl>
            <Notification>
                <Id>04l28000007F0qPAAS</Id>
                <sObject xsi:type="sf:Case" xmlns:sf="urn:sobject.enterprise.soap.sforce.com">
                    <sf:Id>5002800000Xbuq7AAB</sf:Id>
                    <sf:Priority>High</sf:Priority>
                    <sf:Reason>Breakdown</sf:Reason>
                    <sf:Status>Escalated</sf:Status>
                    <sf:Subject>aaaaaaaaaaaaa</sf:Subject>
                </sObject>
            </Notification>
        </notifications>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

**Notification Response sent:**

```
<?xml version= \"1.0\" encoding= \"UTF-8\"?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <soapenv:Body>
        <notificationsResponse xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2005/09/outbound">
            <Ack>true</Ack>
        </notificationsResponse>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

**Screen  Shots Below :**

[image: soapMessage]

[image: Delivery Failure Reason]

Answer (score 0):

This issue got resolved, the root cause being i have not flushed the OutputStreamWriter.

Though the above code contains write.flush() at the end and it works.